# Smooth Scrolling for specific anchor links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I'm using Google's smooth scrolling script for a specific anchor link `#tothetop` and not with any `#` only. I've done this in the example.js file (that you download with the script):

Changed:

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function() { ... });
```

To:

```
$('a[href*=#tothetop]').click(function() { ... });
```

So now it only applies the smooth scrolling to `#tothetop`, but how would I apply it to other different anchor links? eg: `#tothetop`, `#tothebottom`, `#gotothepub`, etc.?
(Don't ask why I'm not using the '#' because that's a long story but in short - it conflicts with another script on the page)
I've tried:

```
$('a[href*=#tothetop]','a[href*=#tothebottom]').click(function() { ... });
```

But this doesn't work. 
I'm not too knowledgeable with Javascript and PHP but I'm sure there's a simple way to do this?

Full code for example.js goes like:

```
$(function(){

$('a[href*=#tothetop]').click(function() {

if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var $target = $(this.hash);

        $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

        if ($target.length) {

            var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;

            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);

            return false;

        }

    }

});

});
```

Comment: should there also be the jquery tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use this, because obviously you name your scrolling anchors all with "toTheAnchor":

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href^=#][href*=to]', function() {});
```

This should select all links starting with "#" and have "to" in the word.

Comment: Wicked! Thanks for that, it is now working :) I just hope other issues don't arrise. Never knew javascript was that versatile :)

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(...);
```

this selector will match all anchors in which `href` attribute is starting with `#`.

Your example is valid but it should be written like so

```
$('a[href*="#tothetop"], a[href*="#tothebottom"]')
```

Note the quotes around the value and the single quotes (used just once).

Comment: WOW - fast reply! I can't use the "#" only cos it conflicts with another script on my page (long story)... I've added that explanation to my question above. Thanks though!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see ^ in your code there. What does the little ^ mean?

Comment: `^=` means an attribute *starting with the value*, while `*=` means an attribute *containing the value*

Comment: Ok great, that does work! BUT, using ^ is now effecting a script on my page. It's a "Like" counter that increases when you click it. That button is obviously linked as a "#" and when I use ^ ... the Like button doesn't work anymore.

Comment: because you return false; in your function

Comment: What must I remove to get rid of the false? (sorry I am definitely no Javascripter). This:if ($target.length) {

            var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;

            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);

            return false;

        }

Comment: so it's better if you provide a prefix to all you anchors e.g. `#section-*` and have a `$('a[href^="#section-"]')` selector

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. Simon below has answered is clearly for me below.

Comment: I just noticed you updated your answer. I'll remember that! Thanks